# Markers (mandatory, output only) no longer shown when view looses focus

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP 4 application (also using Riena) with a number of perspectives, several of which contain a master/detail view. The master and detail views are typically in separate stacks. Most detail views contain fields that are marked as mandatory or output only. Most (if not all) of the views use the RCP 3 compatibility layer (changing that is out of the question at the moment, i am afraid).

My problem is this:

- When the detail views loose focus (for example by clicking in the master view or another window) none of those markers are shown any longer, instead all fields appear as if they have no markers.
- Bringing the focus back to the application, the view or any specific field does not show the markers again.

Attempting to actually type into the fields marked as "output only" does not work. This would indicate the marker still exist.

When manipulating the view i can get the markers to show up again, under certain circumstances. For example in one detail view there are two tabs. The first tab contains a number of fields that tend to loose their markers. When i switch from the first tab to the second and then back to the first all markers in that tab are visible again.

Originally i thought the markers may be removed or disabled, but debugging does not indicate this to be true. At the moment i suspect it is a rendering issues, unfortunately i do not have the first clue how Eclipse handles that.

So i guess my question is this:

- Does anybody have any idea what causes the markers to be hidden?
- How can i stop that from happening? If that is not feasible, how can i make them show up again after the view gains focus again?

Comment: What do mean by 'markers'? Show us some code.

Comment: @greg-449 This is part of Eclipse [Riena](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/rt.riena). It puts something called "ridget" between the actual UI element and the rest of the logic. Markers are part of Riena, which are used to mark a widget as readonly (here called output only), mandatory and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed an applied theme and the application behaves as it should now.